# adding a record to a LINQ object (concat) taking values from another

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi i'm looking for some help in how to append rows to an existing LINQ object. In the controller method below I have two result sets, i'm looping the Sites and want to add a record to the 'results' object for each record in the Sites object.

I've tried concat etc but not getting anywhere, just need s small example to assist, many thanks in advance, J

```
public IQueryable<UsersToSite> FindAllUsersToSites(int userId,SystemType obj)
{

    var results = (from usersToSite in this._db.UsersToSites
           where usersToSite.UserId == userId &&
           usersToSite.SystemTypeId == obj
           orderby usersToSite.Site.SiteDescription
           select usersToSite);

    // Now for each remaining Site append a record thats not physically in the database. From the view the user will be able to click these records to ADD new
    // I'll then build in a search
    var sites = (from site in this._db.Sites
                 where !(from o in _db.UsersToSites where (o.UserId == userId && o.SystemTypeId == obj) select o.SiteId).Contains(site.SiteId)
           orderby site.SiteDescription
           select site);

    foreach (var site in sites)
    {

        // HERE I want to create the new ROW in results object
        //results = new[results] { new { UsersToSiteId = null, AccessTypeId = null } }.Concat(sites);

            //SiteId=site.SiteId,
            //UsersToSiteId = 0,
            //AccessTypeId = 0,
            //UserId = userId


    }

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can, if you want to have keep queryable.
However, if you materialize the results with ToList(), then you can:

```
var sites = (from site in this._db.Sites
                where !(from o in _db.UsersToSites where (o.UserId == userId && o.SystemTypeId == obj) select o.SiteId).Contains(site.SiteId)
                orderby site.SiteDescription
                select site)
                .ToList();
sites.Add(new Site { UsersToSiteId = null, etc });
```

If it was LINQ to Objects, you could do `Concat`.
The problem here that it can't do `Concat`LINQ query that will have one part from SQL and another from objects. You need to materialize results first and then concat to object.

Comment: This appears to be working but now the results object is TOLIST and i'm trying to return a IQueryable<UsersToSite> object. Do you know how i can convert results from a list object back to what it was after the ADD

Comment: @John - You can do `return sites.AsQueryable()`, but you need to review your code if you really want to do this.